# Enforcing referential constraints on nullable foreign keys in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship

What is the best approach to making sure that a nullable foreign key value is checked for referential integrity if it is not null?  I can add the logic to ValidateEntity, but this creates a need for a trip to the database for every nullable foreign key field with a value. I am using Entity Framework 5 Model First.

---

We did not have the foreign key constraint declared in the database, just had the relevant fields mapped to an EF association in the model.  Once I added the FK constraint on the DB, everything worked as expected.  I thought from reading about EF that it could enforce a FK constraint based on an association mapping alone, but now I think it relies on the database constraint. Can anyone tell me if this is correct?  If not, how can I edit my EF Model to enforce the constraint?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to avoid a foreign key constraint exception when you save an entity that has a FK property set? Running a query is the only way to check if the referenced entity exists, I think.

Comment: Actually, I want to cause a foreign key constraint error if the value is set and does not exist already.  I want no error if I save the record with the nullable FK field null.  As it is, EF happily lets me save the record with a FK value that doesn't exist.